# Cannot GET / Nodejs Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm using the tutorial found here: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#create-a-simple-web-server and added the following code.

```
// Module dependencies.
var application_root = __dirname,
express = require( 'express' ), //Web framework
path = require( 'path' ), //Utilities for dealing with file paths
mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ); //MongoDB integration

//Create server
var app = express();

// Configure server
app.configure( function() {
//parses request body and populates request.body
app.use( express.bodyParser() );

//checks request.body for HTTP method overrides
app.use( express.methodOverride() );

//perform route lookup based on url and HTTP method
app.use( app.router );

//Where to serve static content
app.use( express.static( path.join( application_root, 'site') ) );

//Show all errors in development
app.use( express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

//Start server
var port = 5000;
app.listen( port, function() {
console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env );
});
```

After starting the server with `node server.js` I'm getting an error stating `Cannot GET /` when I access `localhost:5000` and I just wondered if anyone knew much about this error as Express and Node are new to me?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you're missing your routes, you need to define at least one route for example '/' to index.

e.g.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {});
});
```

Comment: You're right - it was a routes issue but the guide suggests that it should work without adding one at this point.

Comment: Depends what you have in your static content folder i.e. site.  If you have an index.html as in the guide's example then it probably will work.

Comment: I do have an HTML file - never mind working now anyway

Comment: There's clearly something else going on in that guide, because it's suggesting that when you go to `localhost:5000` that you get a fully developed HTML result, and that's nowhere to be found in the code you listed.

Comment: Yes that's from earlier on but not really connected with the bit I had an issue with.

Comment: I'm working through the same thing and have the same error ... but I'm not clear where this app.get line goes ... also where does the res variable come from?

Comment: @mikerodent Good spot Re res variable, the answer was missing the function handler which provides both request and response variables as per expressjs.com/api.  Also, you define the routes in your service/app.js, using the question's code as an example I would put them just before `//Start server`; after the service is configured but before it is started.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked your folder structure? It seems to me like Express can't find your root directory, which should be a a folder named "site" right under your default directory. Here is how it should look like, according to the tutorial:

```
node_modules/
  .bin/
  express/
  mongoose/
  path/
site/
  css/
  img/
  js/
  index.html
package.json
```

For example on my machine, I started getting the same error as you when I renamed my "site" folder as something else. So I would suggest you check that you have the index.html page inside a "site" folder that sits on the same path as your server.js file.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

Much like leonardocsouza, I had the same problem. To clarify a bit, this is what my folder structure looked like when I ran `node server.js`

```
node_modules/
app/
  index.html
  server.js
```

After printing out the `__dirname` path, I realized that the `__dirname` path was where my server was running (`app/`).

So, the answer to your question is this:

If your `server.js` file is in the same folder as the files you are trying to render, then

```
app.use( express.static( path.join( application_root, 'site') ) );
```

should actually be

```
app.use(express.static(application_root));
```

---

The only time you would want to use the original syntax that you had would be if you had a folder tree like so:

```
app/
  index.html
node_modules
server.js
```

where `index.html` is in the `app/` directory, whereas `server.js` is in the root directory (i.e. the same level as the `app/` directory).

**Side note:** Intead of calling the `path` utility, you can use the syntax `application_root + 'site'` to join a path.

Overall, your code **could** look like:

```
// Module dependencies.
var application_root = __dirname,
express = require( 'express' ), //Web framework
mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ); //MongoDB integration

//Create server
var app = express();

// Configure server
app.configure( function() {

    //Don't change anything here...

    //Where to serve static content
    app.use( express.static( application_root ) );

    //Nothing changes here either...
});

//Start server --- No changes made here
var port = 5000;
app.listen( port, function() {
    console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env );
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting this error, it could be because you don't have a route defined for your get.

For example:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/people', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello');
})

app.listen(3000);


http://http://localhost:3000/people --> this works
http://http://localhost:3000 --> this will output Cannot GET / message.
```

Comment: This is what I was getting. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

## Reason of the problem

Generally reason for such problem is that you forgot to use your router

So you need to call something like

#### app.use(router);

router in this case is nothing but express Router instance
const router = Router();