# Deleting table rows from Mysql using Node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sql-delete

Im having trouble with deleting a table row from the Mysql database. When I click on the button "Delete" on the website, it has to completely remove the content from that row. This is my code:

Index.ejs:

```
    <% if(pictures.length){ %>     
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Driver</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                    <th>Location</th>                       
                    <% if(admin) { %>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    <% } %>
                </tr>
    <% } %>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/<%= pictures[i].image %>" /></td>
                <td><%= pictures[i].driver %></td>
                <td><%= pictures[i].team %></td>
                <td><%= pictures[i].location %></td>                    
                <% if(admin) { %>
                <td><a href="edit/<%= pictures[i].id %>" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="/<%= pictures[i].id %>">Delete</a></td>
                <% } %>

    <% } %>
            </tr>                   
            </table>    

</div>
```

edit.js:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query("DELETE FROM pictures WHERE id = ? ", [id], function(err, results) {
         res.redirect('/');
         console.log('Some data has been deleted')
    });
  });
});
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Cannot GET /10 
(10 is the ID from that table)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317981/cannot-get-nodejs-error

Comment: Nope, unfortunatly. All other routes working correct

Comment: Did you try this by removing the [ ] in your query? So just put the variable name.

Comment: As an aside, it's generally considered a bad practice to make modifications to database (unsafe methods) on a `GET` method. Crawlers assume `GET` is safe and doesn't cause side-effects.