# Npm: Getting cannot get / error after publishing my package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-publish

I am having a npm package which serves as a local host. What I want is after user use `npm install -g` to install it, they can use the command `easydx` to run the local host and web pages can be served as in a static server.

During development, it works fine with `npm start` and the pages can successfully open at localhost:3666. But when I publish the package and tested it using `npm install -g` to install it. After `easydx` successfully fires the server, localhost:3666 get the cannot get / error.

My package contains the line:

```
  "bin": {
    "easydx": "index.js"
  },
```

and my index.js file begins with

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
```

So what is going wrong here?

In my index.js file:

I have used:

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));
```

to serve the static web files. And have used express routes for the web service.

Comment: show your server.js file

Comment: @krishankTripathi I don't have one. I only have the index.js which is the entry point. Is that the one you are asking for?

Comment: then where you are defining the router to get the response on the particular link i.e local host:3666

Comment: @krishankTripathi in index.js file

Comment: could you show me how you call the request function

Comment: @krishankTripathi Updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167637/discussion-between-krishank-tripathi-and-lance-shi).

Comment: Is dist folder your root folder and contains all the files if not and you are creating a virtual path prefix then you can check this https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: here i have found a question that might be helpful if you have path issue in your js script that i think it has so please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot GET / Nodejs Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317981/cannot-get-nodejs-error)

Comment: @krishankTripathi Thanks a lot for all the comments and research. But the difference between my case and those issues are the project runs successfully with node index.js

Comment: @krishankTripathi But it doesn't work after npm link