# Unable to access vue 3 site running on docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, vite

I have managed to get a vue 3 vite application running on docker using this set up in `docker-compose.yml` file

```
frontend:
  image: node:lts
  working_dir: /var/www/html/app/
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  volumes:
    - ./frontend/:/var/www/html/app
  tty: true
```

However when I hit `localhost:3000`, I am unable to reach the site. From my research, I have modified `package.json` script adding host to it

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173"
  },
```

and in `vite.config.js` I have added a server attribute to it

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

After doing this, I still haven't been successful visiting the application.

What can I do to fix this challenge I am having?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `/var/www/html/app/` is the location from which your files will be served on defined port 3000,
Just to be sure, have you checked generating the build of the application and copied the output to above destination. The build command could be `npm run build`

Comment: Yes `/var/www/html/app` is the path where the app lives on the docker container. I have did not build the application using `npm run build`. Do I need to do that since I am working on my local docker set up?

Comment: If you want to serve it using any web server then you need to build it and place the artifacts in that location, else if you are looking to serve it using embedded server for immediate change effect then you may need to run preview script

Comment: So I added `command: ['npm', 'run', 'preview']` to docker compose file. The container is successfully started but I still cannot reach the app at `localhost:3000`

Comment: Did you modified this port number defined here in json file `vite preview --port 4173` to 3000

Comment: Yes. I actually left it to use 4173 and changed 3000 to 4173. But now I get `Cannot GET /` when trying to reach the app at `localhost:4173`...at least I see something now. Any idea?

Comment: This means server started successfully, but there were no files at location to be served, you can refer more about this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317981/cannot-get-nodejs-error